# Java Polymorphism: Dynamic method dispatch (A liitle help needed)

Tags: java

What is happening in the line :
Sup supref;

is that a type of variable? 
Brief explanation of needed please.

is ref a keyword? I've never seen this before it has kinda of just appeared with no explanation in my text book. much appreciated.

Entire code:

```
class Sup { 
void who() {
    System.out.println("who() in Sup");
}

}

class Sub1 extends Sup {
void who() {
    System.out.println("who() in Sub1");
}
}

class Sub2 extends Sup {
void who() {
    System.out.println("who() in Sub2");
}
}

public class DynDispDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sup superOb = new Sup();
    Sub1 subOb1 = new Sub1();
    Sub2 subOb2 = new Sub2();

    Sup supref;

    supref = superOb;
    supref.who();

    supref = subOb1;
    supref.who();

    supref = subOb2;
    supref.who();
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly of the question, but yes `Sup supref;` is the declaration of the variable `supref` of type `Sup`. Maybe try another Java textbook if this one doesn't tell you properly about creation of variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sup supref;
```

means that `supref` is a variable of type `Sup`. `supref` can reference any object of class `Sup` or any of it's subclasses.

Comment: @heathbm: It's the same as `int number;` It's just the name given to a variable that isn't initialized yet.

Comment: A variable in Java can be either any one of primitive types e.g. int, char, float, double, boolean etc. or of a class- type. In this case it is of type Sup which is a class. When the variable is of class-type, it can reference any object of that class or it's subclasses. That means in this case it can refer to superOb, subOb1, subOb2 etc. Please read this for further clarification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

Comment: My source of learning skipped that variables could be of type class. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Sup supref;
```

This line declares a variable who's name is `supref`, of type `Sup`, that is not initialized (it essentially references nothing).

This variable is able to hold a reference to an object of type `Sup`, or any of its subclasses, but cannot be used to do anything until it's initialized using `new`, or by some other assignment operation, such as `supref = superOb;`, which assigns the reference pointed at by `superOb`, which is of type `Sup` as well.

The following code in your example illustrates polymorphism, as there are assignments being made to `supref` from objects of different types and calling the `who()` method on those objects.

You can use a single variable to hold a reference to some supertype and not be concerned with the subclass type, and use the interface defined to get proper functionality.

Answer (score 0):

supref is a variable of type Sup. It is also called a reference variable in Java. Since 'Sup' is the parent class to Sub1 and Sub2, it means that Sub1 and Sub2 are also of type Sup. That means, any reference variable that is of type Sup can be used to reference an object which is of type Sup, which in this case, is used to hold the reference for Sub1 and Sub2.